# An error occurs when you try to insert a specific string into the mariaDB table. Any solution?

Tags: mariadb

We are currently developing a platform app with react / express /mariaDB. When a user inputs a new category, I want to create the category as a table. This causes an error when writing the code. Any solution?

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
    const title = "insert"
    const sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE (?) (  `user_key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `user_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`user_key`))";
    connection.query(sqlQuery, [title], (err, errcode,result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err, errcode);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Good!");
        }
    })
});
```

error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('insert') (  `user_key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `user_id` VARCHAR(45) ...' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "CREATE TABLE ('insert') (  `user_key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `user_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`user_key`))"
```

Comment: `INSERT` is a reserved keyword in all DBMS systems. You can't name a table `INSERT` without special handling, and you'll hate all the hoops you have to jump through in order to use such a table.

Comment: [create table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) doesn't put parenthesis around the tablename. Also same page, autoincrement must be part of a KEY.

Comment: const title = "abc" not use Insert.. but error is triggered. Cannot use this Code?

Comment: If you use ?, you have to use +title+ to create a single quote.

Comment: @이태희, if that ^ is the complete fix can you document this as an answer for the next person that encounters this probelm